# How can I uninstall Anaconda2 and install Anaconda3?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Why do I want to do that:

Because, I want to install python3, opencv3, opencv2, and tensorflow0.12. I am trying but can not install python3 in Anaconda2!

And

Upgraded version!

Comment: conda env... Don't reinstall anything

Comment: How can I use `env`? Is it like I can create different environments for different project?

Comment: @cricket_007 could create an `env`. But, when I run `python` and then `import cv2`, it works fine. But, when I start `jupyter notebook` and then `import cv2`, it does not work.

Comment: Then the `jupyter`  binary is not using the environment with `cv2` installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `conda install python=3`. See https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html or http://chris35wills.github.io/conda_python_version/ .

Comment: I could install and create an env. But, when I run python and then import cv2, it works fine. But, when I start jupyter notebook and then import cv2, it does not work.

Comment: @cricket_007 I did because that solves the problem of Anaconda2/3 and Python3 installation. I thought not to create a new question just for `jupyter`.

Comment: @Raavi, it's hard to judge what's going on from the information you've provided. Did you install python 3 in your main Anaconda environment, or in a separate environment? Are you running on Windows, Mac or Linux? How do you normally launch python or jupyter notebook?

Comment: @mfripp I just found on stackoverflow to run a command `conda install nb_conda` and it is running fine now. Btw, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and installed in main&seperate env.